# Upgrading cvxpy Using pip3 Failed

Tags: python, pip, cvxpy

I got this error when upgrading cvxpy using pip3. Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks. The platform is OS X 10.11.2.

```
Collecting cvxpy
  Using cached cvxpy-0.3.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cvxopt>=1.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from cvxpy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ecos>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from cvxpy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scs>=1.1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from cvxpy)
Collecting multiprocess (from cvxpy)
  Using cached multiprocess-0.70.3.tgz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/94/v_wjnx7x62n8x7dfr_734zy80000gn/T/pip-build-bwub59jx/multiprocess/setup.py", line 66, in <module>
        meta_fh = open(os.path.join(here, '%s/__init__.py' % libdir))
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/94/v_wjnx7x62n8x7dfr_734zy80000gn/T/pip-build-bwub59jx/multiprocess/py3.5/multiprocess/__init__.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/94/v_wjnx7x62n8x7dfr_734zy80000gn/T/pip-build-bwub59jx/multiprocess
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you under Python 3.5?

If so it seems like the dependency to `multiprocess` has not been updated to python 3.5. However the installation scripts for 3.4 worked for me:

1. Go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocess and download the 0.70.3.tgz file (bottom of the page)
2. `tar -xvzf multiprocess-0.70.3.tgz`
3. `cd multiprocess-0.70.3` then `mv py3.4 py3.5`
4. `python3 setup.py build`
5. `python3 setup.py install`
6. `pip3 install cvxpy`
7. `pip3 install nose`
8. `nosetests cvxpy` should now work.

Comment: I apologize for this issue. We're dropping ``multiprocess`` in the next major update.